# Does SharePoint internally use Server Object Model?

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint has given the provision to access its database through the following options

1. Server Object Model
2. Client Object Model
3. Web Services

Does SharePoint Website itself use Server object model internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. Obviously, some areas of the object model are private to itself, but if it's available, you're using the same stuff that SharePoint does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree to Andy Burns answer, but let make some clearance. All stuff working by next scheme

```
Client Object        Server       COM wrappers        Unmanaged  
    Models      <->  Object  <->        &       <->  Native Code  <->  DataBases
 Web Services   <->  Model         COM objects          (core)
```

Yeah, that's right, internally SharePoint still works in old legacy unmanaged code because the first version was released before .NET Framework born.

Comment: Thanks Andy & Oleg for your answers.